# how to show table values with no refernece in other table in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am using hibernate and i want to display only those records of table A that do not have refrence in table B.i.e. Table A has primary key jobId,which is foreign key in table B. Now I want to display only those id values that are not present in Table B.

Comment: I fail to see the relationship between your question, and the code you pasted. And how can A.jobId be a foreign key to the table B, if the jobId can be absent from table B? A foreign key is null, or it references some existing row. If it doesn't reference anything, it's not a foreign key anymore.

Comment: basic sql part buddy, just have a look at sql IN/NOT IN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 select a from A a where a.jobId not in (select b.jobId from B b)
```